# sigset: ignoring ctrl-c in Unix

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to make my program ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in unix which seems to work, the issue is that it keep writing "Syntax error". Here is the code

```
extern "C" void ignore( int sig )
{            
    fprintf( stderr, "\n"); // Print a new line
    // This function does nothing except ignore ctrl-c
}

int main()
{           
    // For ctrl-c
    sigset( SIGINT, ignore );

    while (1) {
        getUserInput();
    }      

    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it runs through getUserInput again, which is the expected behavior, but it writes "Syntax error" as well. I checked and the "ignore" function gets executed, and once it has been executed, then it prints the error message, I am not sure why.

Does anyone have any clues please?

Thank you very much,

Jary

Comment: If this is C, why the `extern "C"`?

Comment: Please post a complete, self-contained program that can be compiled.  I see at least two things in here that _might_ be your problem, but I can't tell for sure without a complete test case.

Comment: If this is new code, you probably want to use `sigaction`; `sigset` is pre-POSIX and deprecated

Comment: Thank you Michael, unfortunately this code will be run on an old Solaris machine and so I have to use sigset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use [`sigset()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sighold.html).  Although it is in POSIX 2008, it is marked obsolescent - and also unsafe in threaded programs.

You then have a choice between [`signal()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html), which is blessed by ISO C but has some undesirable characteristics, and [`sigaction()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) which is the preferred solution in POSIX systems.

One key point with signal handling is to ensure you do not trap any signals that are ignored when you enter the program - unless you know something that the caller can't (such as you need to trap SIGCHLD signals for dead children).

This leads to the standard formulations, preached since time immemorial, for `signal()`:

```
if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)
    signal(SIGINT, ignore);
```

Or, for `sigaction()`:

```
struct sigaction new_sa;
struct sigaction old_sa;
sigfillset(&new_sa.sa_mask);
new_sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
new_sa.sa_flags = 0;

if (sigaction(SIGINT, &new_sa, &old_sa) == 0 && old_sa.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
{
    new_sa.sa_handler = ignore;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &new_sa, 0);
}
```

Since you do not show us the `getUserInput()` function, there is no way we can prognosticate on why you see 'Syntax Error'.  However, if you have a grammar at work, it may well be that your read is not returning valid data, and the parser is unhappy with what is left in the buffer for it to process.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Indeed, getUserInput is a large grammar at work, I believe you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

(Note: for more portability, you should probably use `signal()` (C standard library) or `sigaction()` (POSIX) instead of `sigset()`, but I don't think that's the problem here.)

You're not really *ignoring* the signal here; you're catching it and taking your own action - but it's likely that a system call has returned an error as a result of the interruption.

e.g. maybe you've caused a `read` system call to fail with `EINTR`.  I suspect the real problem is that some code inside `getUserInput()` is not handling this error case.

You can ignore the signal completely by setting the handler to the special value `SIG_IGN`, which should work with any of `sigset()`, `signal()` or `sigaction()`.

Answer (score 1):

The "Syntax Error" message must be coming from the `getUserInput` function (or something it calls, of course) -- you could investigate by having that function print out what it is receiving and why it is complaining.

Note that the canonical way to ignore a signal is to use the pre-defined `SIG_IGN` as the signal handler.  e.g.
`sigset(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)`

Answer (score 1):

`ignore()` does a lot more than nothing.

When you run this code on UNIX, `SIGINT` is delivered asynchronously on the same thread that is executing `getUserInput()`. If a `SIGINT` arrives while `getUserInput()` is accessing `stderr`, the behavior is undefined because `fprintf()` usually isn't designed to be reentrant. (However, the behavior is likely to include garbled and/or repeated output. Did your program print "Syntax Error" before the `SIGINT` was delivered?) [CERT](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers) and [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Nonreentrancy.html) have some more info about this.

If you were running this code on Win32, `SIGINT` would be delivered asynchronously [in a separate thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/28/8781423.aspx).